# Disproportional overflow scrolling on scaled element

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, scale

I'm creating a HTML Canvas pixel art game.

I've got a problem with the scaling being disproportionate.

The `div` that wraps most of the DOM as the following styling:

```
.ui {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

This works well and all content is nicely scaled.

But then I've got a nested structure something along the lines of:

`.ui > .wrapper > .side-bar > .content-holder > .shop > .shop-entries`

That last one `.shop-entries` has  the following style:

```
.shop-entries {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Its parent `.shop` has the following styles:

```
.shop {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

For some reason, the scroll is going twice as fast as it's meant to.
See gif:

[image: weird scrolling behaviour]

Did anyone fight with this before?

Comment: It might help to include the relevant HTML code to [demonstrate the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @showdev Okay my bad will try to create the Minimal, Reproducible Example thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @showdev i've reposted with example please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67513883/disproportionate-scrolling-on-element-with-an-overlaying-pointer-eventsnone-el Thanks for that.